# How can I install a hierarchy of files using CMake?

Tags: cmake

I've created a list of files using:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE DEPLOY_FILES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/install/*")
```

I want to install all of these files in `/usr/myproject/`, but I want to maintain the file tree on the installed folder:

```
install/junk
install/other/junk2
install/other/junk3
```

If I use:

```
install(FILES ${DEPLOY_FILES} DESTINATION "usr/myproject")
```

All the files end up in /usr/myproject as:

```
/usr/myproject/junk
/usr/myproject/junk2
/usr/myproject/junk3
```

How can I make the install command keep track of relative paths?

I've worked around the issue by doing it manually in a `for` loop:

```
set(BASE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/install")
foreach(ITEM ${DEPLOY_FILES})
  get_filename_component(ITEM_PATH ${ITEM} PATH)
  string(REPLACE ${BASE} "" ITEM_PATH ${ITEM_PATH})
  install(FILES ${ITEM} DESTINATION "usr/myproject${ITEM_PATH}")
endforeach()
```

...but this is annoying to do. Surely there's an easier way?

(I can't see anything in the install documentation though...)

Comment: It's simply amusing how f*&ing difficult they can make a trivial **`cp -r`** operation.

Comment: Except they don't.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use:

```
INSTALL( DIRECTORY <directory> DESTINATION usr/myproject )
```

(See here for details: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:install)

`INSTALL( DIRECTORY ... )` preserves the directory structure. But, if you use `install` as `<directory>`, you would end up with `usr/myproject/install/....` which is not what you want.

There are two ways to do this:

1. Use `INSTALL( FILES .... DESTINATION usr/myproject)` to install the files that lie directly in `install/`, then use `INSTALL( DIRECTORY .... DESTINATION usr/myproject`) and manually list the directories to install.
2. Use your globbing command in your original post, and then determine which entries are files, which are directories, move the directory entries to a separate list, feed the lists to `INSTALL( FILES ...)` and `INSTALL( DIRECTORY ...)`, respectively.

   ```
   file(GLOB DEPLOY_FILES_AND_DIRS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/install/*")
   foreach(ITEM ${DEPLOY_FILES_AND_DIRS})
      IF( IS_DIRECTORY "${ITEM}" )
         LIST( APPEND DIRS_TO_DEPLOY "${ITEM}" )
      ELSE()
         LIST( APPEND FILES_TO_DEPLOY "${ITEM}" )
      ENDIF()
   endforeach()
   INSTALL( FILES ${FILES_TO_DEPLOY} DESTINATION usr/myproject )
   INSTALL( DIRECTORY ${DIRS_TO_DEPLOY} DESTINATION usr/myproject )
   ```

*Note:* Depending on the type of files you install, other `INSTALL( ...)` commands might be more appropriate (for example, `INSTALL( TARGETS .... )` to install your libraries/executables.

Comment: @Fraser Thanks for editing, I totally missed the wrong formatting.

Answer (score 89):

The simplest way to install everything from a given directory is:

```
install(DIRECTORY mydir/ DESTINATION dir/newname)
```

**Trailing '/' is significant.**
Without it `mydir` would be installed to `newname/mydir`.

From the CMake documentation:

> The last component of each directory name is appended to the destination
>   directory but a trailing slash may be used to avoid this because it
>   leaves the last component empty.

Comment: This is a much simpler solution that globbing etc. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks by "Trailing '/' is significant."

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 42):

I am assuming you have a **list of files**, let's say `INCLUDE_FILES`. Possibly a selection of files spread over a number of subdirectories, e.g. header files from across the source tree, as opposed to everything in a single subdir like in the other answers.

You can loop over the file list and use `get_filename_component()` to extract the directory part, then use that in a subsequent `install()` to set the `DESTINATION` subdirectory:

```
foreach ( file ${INCLUDE_FILES} )
    get_filename_component( dir ${file} DIRECTORY )
    install( FILES ${file} DESTINATION include/${dir} )
endforeach()
```

Done. ;-)

**Edit:** If all the files you want to install that way match a particular file pattern -- e.g. "all header files" -- then [brno's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67883070/60281) has the edge over this one.

Comment: This is a really good and simple answer. No need to do tricks other than parsing the files list and install them one at a time. +1

Comment: This is absolutely better than `install(DIRECTORY DESTINATION)` since I have maintained a list of header files and want to use that list. +1 :-)

Answer (score 6):

Since globbing is not recommended, and running loops in `CMakeLists.txt` files is clunky, a [pattern matching option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html?highlight=install#installing-directories) of `DIRECTORY` did the trick for me.

```
install(DIRECTORY src/ DESTINATION include FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h")
```

This took the entire folder structure inside `src/` and reproduced it within `<INSTALL_DIR>/include`, header files only.

Comment: Very nice, gave you a shoutout in my answer.