# How can I copy/move a specific set of files during 'make install' using cmake?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I would like to install a certain set of headers (which is not identical to all headers in a directory) to an include directory during make install of my project.

Here is the file structure that I have:

```
MyProject
|-build
|-lib
|-include
|-src
  |-A
  | |-a1.cpp/.h
  | |-a2.cpp/.h
  | |-a3.cpp/.h
  |
  |-B
  | |-b1.cpp/.h
  | |-b1.cpp/.h
  |
  |-CMakeLists.txt
```

In `MyProject/src/CMakeLists.txt` (which is the main CMakeLists file), I setup my project and compile everything into a library.
During the install step (i.e. make install) I would like to move my build `libmyproject.a` to `MyProject/lib` and *some* headers, say `A/a1.h` and `B/b1.h` to the `MyProject/include` folder.

**However, I want to maintain the relative paths of those headers!**

I.e., I want to achieve this:

```
MyProject
|-build
|-lib
| |-libmyproject.a
|
|-include
| |-A
| | |-a1.h
| |
| |-B
|   |-b1.h
|
|-src
  |-...
```

Installing the library is easy with CMake:

set( CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "path_to_my_project")
    install(TARGETS myproject
      ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    )

Where I struggle is the headers. I have a simple list of my API headers:

set(my_api_headers
      A/a1.h
      B/b1.h
    )

But I cannot simply use the 'install(FILES ...)' CMake command as that strips away the relative paths. All the other suggestions I have found so far involce the 'install(DIRECTORY ...)' form with a 'PATTERN', but I don't think I can use that as that 
would copy all headers. (Compare, for example, [How can I install a hierarchy of files using cmake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096471/how-can-i-install-a-hierarchy-of-files-using-cmake))

I tried a simple function

```cmake
############################################################
#
# FUNCTION: install API header files
#
function(install_api_headers
  API_HDRS
  DST_DIR
)

foreach( _header ${${API_HDRS}} )
  file(INSTALL ${_header} 
    DESTINATION ${DST_DIR}
  )
endforeach( _header )

endfunction(install_api_headers)
#
############################################################

install_api_headers(my_api_headers "MyProject/include")
```

but that obviously (well, I remembered when I ran it... :/) is executed during CMake runtime and not during 'make install'...
Trying the easy fix with a 'install(CODE ...)' wrapper also didn't work... :(

install(CODE "install_api_headers(workmodel_API_HDRS 
      {CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${include_DIR_NAME}/WorkModels/${workmodel_NAME})"
    )

So, bottom line:Any hint, idea, link related on how to get this done would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Claus

Comment: Would https://www.semipol.de/archives/251 be helpful?

Comment: @wojciii : Yes, that actually is the solution - and in my mind a better solution as the one you provided via your dropbox example (which I didn't find to replicate what I wanted...)

Comment: @wojciii : If you edit your answer to point to semipol.de/archives/251 I'll reward the "Accepted Answer" to that.

Comment: Done. What my example lacks is INSTALL(FILES testA.hpp DESTINATION "include/A") instead of INSTALL(FILES testA.hpp DESTINATION "include"). Unless I don't understand your question ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

semipol.de/archives/251 appears to solve the issue:

From the link:

```
SET(HS folder/test.h folder/other/test2.h)

A simple call to INSTALL doesn’t preserve the folder structure:

INSTALL(FILES ${HS} DESTINATION include)

This results in all files being directly under $prefix/include.

To preserve the structure you can use this simple macro:

MACRO(INSTALL_HEADERS_WITH_DIRECTORY HEADER_LIST)

FOREACH(HEADER ${${HEADER_LIST}})
STRING(REGEX MATCH "(.*)[/\]" DIR ${HEADER})
INSTALL(FILES ${HEADER} DESTINATION include/${DIR})
ENDFOREACH(HEADER)

ENDMACRO(INSTALL_HEADERS_WITH_DIRECTORY)

INSTALL_HEADERS_WITH_DIRECTORY(HS)
```

I made an example which I thought solved the problem (my way :)):

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68798379/cmake-install-example.tar.bz2

```
$ ./gen-linux.sh 
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.2
..

$ cd linux/
$ make
Scanning dependencies of target LIBB
[ 20%] Building CXX object src/B/CMakeFiles/LIBB.dir/testB.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object src/B/CMakeFiles/LIBB.dir/internalB.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library libLIBB.a
[ 40%] Built target LIBB
Scanning dependencies of target LIBA
[ 60%] Building CXX object src/A/CMakeFiles/LIBA.dir/testA.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object src/A/CMakeFiles/LIBA.dir/internalA.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library libLIBA.a
[ 80%] Built target LIBA
Scanning dependencies of target TESTLIB
[100%] Building C object CMakeFiles/TESTLIB.dir/src/dummy.c.o
Linking C static library libTESTLIB.a
[100%] Built target TESTLIB

$ make install
[ 40%] Built target LIBB
[ 80%] Built target LIBA
[100%] Built target TESTLIB
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: cmake-install-example/build/linux/../../lib/libTESTLIB.a
-- Installing: cmake-install-example/build/linux/../../include/testA.hpp
-- Installing: cmake-install-example/build/linux/../../include/testB.hpp
```

Highlights:

- create two static libraries (LIBA, LIBB) which contain private header files.
- merge the two libs defined in src into one final library (TESTLIB).
- install the merged library into "lib" directory.
- install only the specified header files into "include" directory.

Kindly notice what CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX is set to in the build/gen-linux.sh script.

Comment: Although a nice example of CMake usage, this doesn't solve my problem of preserving relative sub-directories when installing header files. (Plus it uses one CMakeList.txt file for each subdir, which, although maybe better, isn't how my problem is set up.)