# How do I ask CMake to copy include directory while running "cmake install"?

Tags: c, cmake, build

Previously, I'm looking for this kind of question but none of them are working as example [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772588/cmake-is-installing-something-to-usr-local-include-and-usr-lib-instead-of-usr) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487256/cmake-how-to-properly-copy-static-librarys-header-file-into-usr-include).

Currently, I'm creating a C library which supposed to outputs a shared library (`*.so` or `*.dll`) file and multiple `*.h` files in a `./include` directory. The shared library is successfully built and installed to `/usr/local/lib`. However, I have no idea how do I tell CMake to copy `*.h` files to the correct destination as below.

- In POSIX: `/usr/local/include`
- In Windows: `C:\<Compiler Path>\include`

I know I could workaround this by copying those `*.h` with Python script or using if-else logic on CMake. But at least tell me if there is a feature in CMake for doing that thing. Thanks!

Here's my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project (
  learn_c_library
  VERSION 1.0.0
  LANGUAGES C
)

# Specify CMake build and output directory
set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/.cmake")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/out")

# Use every .c file inside ./src
file(GLOB_RECURSE MY_SOURCE_PATH "src/*")

add_library(
  ${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
  ${MY_SOURCE_PATH}
)
include_directories(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  "include/"
)

# Allows "make install" to install shared library
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME})
```

Comment: Can you show us what your current CMakeLists.txt looks like? Normally your CMake file defines *what* to install, and the caller defines *where* to install it, but you can override this if you really must.

Comment: [It is best practice to not use globs in CMake](https://alexreinking.com/blog/how-to-use-cmake-without-the-agonizing-pain-part-2.html), but if you absolutely refuse to list your sources, then at the _very, very least_ use `CONFIGURE_DEPENDS`.

Comment: Never set variable `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`. This variable is automatically set by CMake and CMake has expectations about its value. But setting the variable you (or a person who build your project) could face with many subtle bugs. It is better to assume variable `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` to be readonly one.

Comment: @AlexReinking wow that's the only reason why I should delete CMakeFiles directory before rebuilding. I like your blog, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Tsyvarev The only reason why I added `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` because Visual Studio Code using `build/` directory by default, but now it seems not relevant anymore. Currently I use [cmake.buildDirectory](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/develop/docs/cmake-settings.md#cmake-settings) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer improves on [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68619809/2137996):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

# ...

include(GNUInstallDirs)

install(DIRECTORY "include/"
        TYPE INCLUDE
        COMPONENT MyProj_Development)
```

The [GNUInstallDirs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html) module provides standard configuration points for customizing a project's install layout. These variables should essentially always be used instead of hardcoding path/directory names.

The `TYPE INCLUDE` argument to `install()` was introduced in CMake 3.14 and uses GNUInstallDirs's `CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR` variable to determine the destination.

Finally, and especially if your project is a library, all your `install()` rules should be given a `COMPONENT` argument to allow splitting files between runtime and development packages (and potentially others like documentation and architecture-independent data files).

Comment: It's confirmed working, but I still confused the difference between `TARGET` and `COMPONENT`. Could you explain please?

Comment: The `COMPONENT` argument allows you to split your package up into, well, multiple components. Have you ever seen something like `libfoo` and `libfoo-dev` and `libfoo-doc` in a Linux distribution? There's more documentation on the CMake website, here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html

Answer (score 0):

After days of fiddling CMake, finally I found the solution!

Let's assume you store your public `*.h` inside `./include` directory, then here's the syntax for installing your `*.h` files to your machine:

```
install(
  DIRECTORY
    "include/" # Your global headers location in the project
  DESTINATION
    include # This is your system's default "include" location
)
```

I got the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11097012/3730834) with `usr/myproject` replaced to be `include`

Comment: You should _not_ hardcode `include`, but rather `include(GNUInstallDirs)` and use the `CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR` variable. See the docs: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GNUInstallDirs.html If you're using recent CMake (which you should be), you can also just write `TYPE INCLUDE` instead of `DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}`. See: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#installing-files